# MySQL identifying names problem

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to identify whether a name belongs to a man or a woman from a large dataset by using MySQL. I couldn't find any common things between those names. How can I identify a name belongs to a woman or a man?

Comment: With an extra column "gender" of type ENUM(M,F)? Names are not necessarily male or female and even if they were, you would need a lookup table to find out. What is this question really about?

Comment: It is just a silly project that my supervisor assigned it to me. He claimed that names can be identified by looking at their lengths. For example, names belong to men are longer than names that belong to women. However, it is nonsense. I asked this question because of this illogical answer. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot sensibly. Get a list of names and the sex it usually corresponds to. Compare your names with that list. And keep in mind that there are names which are common for women **and** men.

Names do not really allow to conclude the gender.